# Fire function on element click

Tags: javascript

When I clicked a button, I want to run one the JavaScript code.

The JavaScript looks like:

```
$('.btn normal orange flr').click(function () {

(new Image()).src="https://secure.adnxs.com/seg?add=2852222&t=2";

(new Image()).src="https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/activity/src=4431932;type=invmedia;cat=kd24cnwg;ord=1?" ;

    });
```

when I click this button, I want to fire this code.

The HTML is:

```
<div class="lightBoxFooter">

    ::before
    <a class="btn mini grey" ng-click="closeDialog()" href="javascript:;">

    Alışverişe Devam Et

</a>
<a class="btn normal orange flr" target="_self" ng-click="trackBasket()" href="/sepetim">

    <i class="icon icon-cart"></i>

 Sepete Git
```

Comment: I would love to help if I had any idea what any of this meant.

Comment: Apart from your selector, you are creating new images and not doing anything with them.

Comment: can u tell what exact issue you are facing ?

Comment: You can learn jQuery here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Answer (score 1):

One problem is your selector is wrong

This

```
$('.btn normal orange flr')
```

should be this

```
$('.btn.normal.orange.flr')
```

Other than that you seem to be mixing jquery with angular, not sure what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I tried this . but when I click button,

Comment: This code couldn't fire

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$('.btn normal orange flr')
```

Isn't right for this:

```
<a class="btn normal orange flr" target="_self" ng-click="trackBasket()" href="/sepetim">
```

It should be:

```
$('.btn.normal.orange.flr')
```

When you have this:

```
 $('.btn normal orange flr').click(function () {
```

You'd expect the HTML to look something like this:

```
<div class='btn'>
  <normal>
    <orange>
      <flr></flr>
    </orange>
  </normal>
</div>
```

Where as having

```
$('.btn.normal.orange.flr')
```

With no spaces, but having `.` inbetween means an element that is a class of `btn`, `normal`, `orange` and `flr` at the same time.

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't work. Maybe its wrong click function I tried very much click function but no one didn't fire.

Comment: Your javascript code isn't really doing anything. You need to tell us what you want it to do. @utku

Comment: Alex I can't good explain because I couldn't add screenshoot. I working in a data firm. So I doing button clicker segmentation in a lot website. So I using some platform for that. And this platform giving this javascript code. Normally When I click button, firing this javascript code. And I can check with "HttpFox" program in mozilla.  I hope you can understand me.

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? @utku

Comment: No I haven't any errors in console. But this code firing another web site. But this code don't fire this site. I trying all day but still I couldn't fire. İf I can send screenshoot maybe you can good understand. But I couldn't send because of stackowerflow don't let me for send.